# Basic group theory question on countable groups and infinite abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory

Here are two (maybe simple) questions.

A: Every countable group $G$ has only countably many distinct subgroups.

B: Every infinite abelian group has atleast one element of infinite order.

Both these statements are false. I am unable to find any counterexamples. Just Hints would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: these aren't very obscure possibilities. You can do both with vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

A) Consider the vector space $V$ over the field of two elements with a countably infinite basis. A countably infinite set has uncountably many subsets.

B) $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You can recycle the example for A in B.

Comment: Yes. I am all for recycling. But I also like some variety.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen: Thanks a lot.